# How to switch to notification popup in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code, protractor

I am automating a script to login into an angularJS(1.5) application using protractor. The problem comes after I login into the system. An angularJS popup comes on the screen on which I cannot click and I am not able to get rid of. I am unable to shift my focus on the notification popup.

HTML code of the OKAY button on notification popup is as follows :

```
<button class="material_button" ng-click="notificationGranted();" style="margin-right: 0px !important;margin-top: 0px !important;margin-left: 1%;cursor: pointer;width: 40%;">
    <span>
        <span>Okay</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

Browser : Chrome
OS : Linux

Notification Popup.jpg

[image]

The code is as follows :

```
this.clickOkayButton = function(){
        browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        browser.wait(function () {
            return browser.wait(function () {
                return element(by.id('notificationPopUp')).isDisplayed();
            }, 2 * 1000)
            .then(function () { return true; }, function (error) { return false; });
     }, 20 * 1000);
     element(by.css('button.material_button')).click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
   browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
    return browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[index]);
  });
```

Try the `index` as 0 or 1 as per your application. Hope this helps you

## 0506

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to switch to it. Check the DOM and you'll notice that is part of it and can be manipulated.

Just add code to wait to be displayed:

```
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css(".material_button"))), 150000, "OK Button is not visible").then(function() {
    element(by.css('.material_button')).click();
})
```